# T-Sql Get Row Count Same Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table. My table includes a column. I want to get same value count then view.

My table like this

```
ID
---
2
2
3
4
2
```

I want to get result table like this:

```
ID | Count
---|---
 2 | 3
 3 | 1
 4 | 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Group By` is what you're looking for.

```
Select Id, Count (*) CountOfRows
From MyTable
Group By Id
```